# IE like browser environment with firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cross-browser

In our project, we have some asp files using deprecated third party `asp` controls.
Those controls function properly in IE8, IE9, IE10. But, they don't function properly in Firefox (I am using Firefox 16.1 and firebug).
Is there any way to get the IE like browser environment to the Firefox temporarily so that I can debug in Firefox?

Comment: Retag this with `cross-browser` instead of `firefox` tag

Comment: @ViralShah: In particular, I need for firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASP isn't processed by the browser...just the HTML, CSS and JS it produces. So, take your page in IE, save it out, then open it in Firefox.